# JS - React - passing parameter to imported const - var = undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

It might be an easy one, but I'm stuck. I hope you can help me out.

I've got a React project. And I've made an arrow function that should return a sluglified slug.
The problem is, that in `slugify()` `input` is `undefined`

**This is my simplified code:**

blog.js

```
import {slugify} from "../slugify";

function mySlugifier(input, type) {
  return  slugify('this is my input', 'blog')
}
```

```
export const slugify = ({input, type}) => {
  return input
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[\s\?\:]+/g, '-')
    .slice(0, 200)
}
```

**How do I properly pass the parameters?**

Answer (score 3):

From the parameter list the `input` and `type` have been destructured like `({input, type})`. And that's the reason why you got `undefined` for `input` originally.

You need pass as the following:

```
slugify({input: 'this is my input', type: 'blog'});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! works like a charm Thanks. I understand now why. Thanks.

Comment: You've missed the closing single quote of the title value.